# Enclosing Logic in Akka Actor Message

Tags: java, mysql, akka, actor, slick

I recently began to learn AKKA, I have created a router actor, there are a bunch of database worker actors sitting behind the router. I have came with this implementation, each worker actor will have one database connection, I enclose database logic into each message (by implementing interface SQLExecutable), actor will execute each message. If the connection dies, exception will be handled by router's supervision strategy.

My question is that I know each message in AKKA should be immutable, here I am enclosing the logic inside the message, I am not sure if this will cause any unexpected behaviour. My intention just want to decouple business logic and database connection.

```
public class TokenRepository {
private static final ActorSelection DB_ROUTER_SELECTION;
private static final String DB_ROUTER_SELECTION_PATH = "/user/JDBCRouter";
private static final int EXECUTE_TIME_OUT = 1000;
private static final String SAVE_TOKEN_STR = "INSERT INTO Tokens " +
        "(uuid, creation, email, expiration, isSignUp) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

private static final String FIND_TOKEN_STR = "SELECT * FROM Tokens " +
        "WHERE uuid = ?";

private static final String DELETE_TOKEN_STR = "DELETE FROM Tokens" +
        "WHERE uuid = ?";


static {
    DB_ROUTER_SELECTION = AkkaActorSystem.getInstance().actorSelection(DB_ROUTER_SELECTION_PATH);
}


private static class saveTokenExecutor implements SQLExecutable {
    private final Token token;

    saveTokenExecutor(Token token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection, UntypedActorContext untypedActorContext) throws SQLException {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SAVE_TOKEN_STR);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, token.getUuid());
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(token.getCreationTime().getMillis()));
        preparedStatement.setString(3, token.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(token.getCreationTime().plusMinutes(5).getMillis()));
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(5, token.getIsSignUp());
        preparedStatement.execute();
        connection.commit();
        untypedActorContext.sender().tell(token, ActorRef.noSender());

    }
}

private static class findTokenExecutor implements SQLExecutable {
    private final String uuid;

    public findTokenExecutor(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection, UntypedActorContext untypedActorContext) throws SQLException {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(FIND_TOKEN_STR);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
        resultSet.next();
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
        token.setIsSignUp(resultSet.getBoolean("isSignUp"));
        token.setCreationTime(new DateTime(resultSet.getTimestamp("creation")));
        token.setExpirationTime(new DateTime(resultSet.getTimestamp("expiration")));
        token.setUuid(resultSet.getString("uuid"));
        connection.commit();
        untypedActorContext.sender().tell(token, ActorRef.noSender());
    }
}

private static class deleteTokenExecutor implements SQLExecutable {
    private final String uuid;

    public deleteTokenExecutor(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection, UntypedActorContext untypedActorContext) throws SQLException {
        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_TOKEN_STR);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
    }
}

public static Future<Token> saveToken(Token token) {
    Future<Object> tokenFuture = ask(DB_ROUTER_SELECTION, new saveTokenExecutor(token), 1000);
    return tokenFuture.flatMap(new Mapper<Object, Future<Token>>() {
        @Override
        public Future<Token> apply(Object parameter) {
            return Futures.successful((Token) parameter);
        }
    }, AkkaActorSystem.getInstance().dispatcher());
}

public static Future<Token> findToken(String uuid) {
    Future<Object> tokenFuture = ask(DB_ROUTER_SELECTION, new findTokenExecutor(uuid), EXECUTE_TIME_OUT);
    return tokenFuture.flatMap(new Mapper<Object, Future<Token>>() {
        @Override
        public Future<Token> apply(Object parameter) {
            return Futures.successful((Token) parameter);
        }
    }, AkkaActorSystem.getInstance().dispatcher());

}

/**
 * delete token
 *
 * @param uuid
 * @return future<int>
 */
public static Future<Object> deleteToken(String uuid) {
    return ask(DB_ROUTER_SELECTION, new deleteTokenExecutor(uuid), EXECUTE_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

```
public class DBWorker extends UntypedActor {
private final String host, user, password, db;
private final int port ;
private java.sql.Connection conn;

private static class DBWorkerCreator implements Creator<DBWorker> {
    private final String host, user, password, db;
    private final int port;

    public DBWorkerCreator(String host, int port, String user, String password, String db){
        this.host = host;
        this.user = user;
        this.port = port;
        this.password = password;
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public DBWorker create() throws Exception {
        return new DBWorker(host, port, user, password, db);
    }
}

public static Props getProps(String host, int port, String user, String password,String db){
    return Props.create(new DBWorkerCreator(host, port, user, password, db));
}

public DBWorker(String host, int port, String user, String password, String db){
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;
    this.db = db;
}

/**
 * initialization: database connection
 */
@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+ host + ":" + port + "/" + db;
        System.out.println(url);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //something happens when connecting to the database, throw exception to DB Router
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}


//cancel post start
@Override
public void postRestart(Throwable reason){

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {


    try {
        if(message instanceof SQLExecutable){
            ((SQLExecutable) message).execute(conn,getContext());
        } else if (message instanceof String){
            conn.createStatement().execute((String)message);
        }
        else {
            // unknown message, do nothing here
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        try {
            //if SQLException is throwing up, rollback
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // something serious happens, throw the exception to DB router
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        }

    } finally {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I would avoid this if I were you.  It just smells funny.  If you really need this behavior (which seems based on the Command Pattern) then you can create a relationship between request messages and command classes to execute when you receive those requests.  This kind of decoupling just feels cleaner, but again, that is purely my opinion.

Comment: I am confused how to handle database (blocking) operations in akka, and I didn't find very much good practices regarding this. So I just gathered some thoughts and implemented a solution. @cmbaxter